# Express $\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi$ in Spherical Harmonics

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, power-series, special-functions

I am looking for a form of $$\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi=\sum_{lm}c_{lm}Y_l^{m}(\theta,\phi),$$
where $Y_{lm}$ is the spherical harmonics. The idea I believe would be to find $$c_{lm}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \mathrm{d\theta}\sin\theta\mathrm{d\phi}Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi.$$ But I am unable to solve the above integral. Any idea on how to obtain full expression in terms of spherical harmonics?

Comment: Well you can also write down a general spherical harmonic in terms of complex exponentials in phi and associated legendre polynomials in cos

Comment: Yes. But I am looking for what combinations of spherical harmonics make $\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi$.

Comment: Actually it is not possible that way, because interestingly $\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi$ contains sum over spherical harmonics of all even order $l$ and $m=(-2,2)$ plus $m=0$.

Comment: It makes doing integrals easier if you know how high of an order you need, for example since you have cosine squared you know the maximum order for $\ell$